# Rails - Best deployment setup with AWS Auto Scaling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, capistrano

I am researching ways to deploy a ruby application to an AWS Autoscaling Group and I'm having a hard time deciding which way is best and finding good content about it.

I have looked into CodeDeploy, Elastic Beanstalk, CloudFormation, Capistrano, Chef and some others. The combination of some of them.

I, personally, didn't want to use Chef or anything that needs much time maintaining. Currently I am using Dokku on EC2, but I need to make a more scalable and elastic solution for a new project.

What would be the best suggestion and study material?

Comment: Have you any experience with [rubber](https://github.com/rubber/rubber)?

Comment: No. I actually just looked into it today. It's an capistrano plugin right? I was looking at the wiki and had the impression that it provisioned the instance for me. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know. I have the same question and problem right now :)

Comment: Would Heroku work for you?

Comment: No, @BenWhaley. Too expensive and I am looking for an elastic solution with autoscaling.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation + ElasticBeanstalk works great.